# 1-to-1 and onto functions

Tags: discrete-mathematics

What is the number of 1-to-1 functions:

1. mapping from the set $\{a, b, c, d\}$ to the set $\{0, 1, 2\}$? I got 6.
2. mapping from the set $\{a, b, c, d\}$ to the set $\{0, 1, 2, 3\}$? I got 24.

What is the number of onto functions:

1. mapping from the set $\{a, b, c, d\}$ to the set $\{0, 1, 2\}$? I got 0.
2. mapping from the set $\{a, b, c, d\}$ to the set $\{0, 1, 2, 3\}$? I got 24.

Are my answers correct? Thanks!

Comment: (i) Can you write down one of those one-to-one functions from $\{a,b,c,d\}$ to $\{1,2,3\}$?

Comment: You need to have a look at the definitions again, there are no 1-1 maps from a 4 element set to a 3 element set.

Comment: I believe that the answer to the first question is $0$, and that the answer to the third question is definitely not $0$.

Answer (score 1):

There are *no* $1$-to-$1$ functions from $\{a,b,c,d\}$ to $\{0,1,2\}$: the pigeonhole principle tells you that if $f:A\to B$, where $A$ has $4$ elements and $B$ has $3$, there must be two different $x,y\in A$ such that $f(x)=f(y)$. Your answer to the second part of that question is correct, however: there are $4$ choices for $f(a)$, then $3$ remaining choices for $f(b)$, and so on, so that there are $4!=24$ possible functions altogether.

Your count of $4!=24$ functions from $\{a,b,c,d\}$ onto $\{0,1,2,3\}$ is also correct, but there are certainly functions from $\{a,b,c,d\}$ onto $\{0,1,2\}$. Such a function must send two elements of $\{a,b,c,d\}$ to the same element of $\{0,1,2\}$, and must send each of the remaining elements of $\{a,b,c,d\}$ to a different one of the two remaining elements of $\{0,1,2\}$. There are $\binom42=6$ ways to choose which two element of $\{a,b,c,d\}$ will have the same image under $f$, and $3$ ways to choose which element of $\{0,1,2\}$ will be that image. Then there are $2$ ways to assign values to the two remaining elements of $\{a,b,c,d\}$. Thus, there are altogether $6\cdot3\cdot2=36$ functiosn from $\{a,b,c,d\}$ onto $\{0,1,2\}$.

Answer (score 0):

You first answer is wrong. There cannot be any 1-1 map from the a set with 4 elements into a set with 3 elements. The second is correct. i.e $4P_4=24$.